# How to fix "addConfigurationProvider(Xml...) is undefined" error in struts 2 blank archetype generated from m2eclipse plugin with Indigo?

Tags: java, struts2, maven-3, m2eclipse

I created a blank struts 2 archetype using maven 3, m2eclipse plugin for eclipse Indigo.  I encountered this error after project generation.

*The method addConfigurationProvider(XmlConfigurationProvider) is undefined for the type 
 ConfigurationManager*

This is from the ConfigTest.java

```
 protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        XmlConfigurationProvider c = new XmlConfigurationProvider("struts.xml");
        configurationManager.addConfigurationProvider(c);
        configurationManager.reload();
    }
```

How do I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `addConfigurationProvider` was marked as deprecated and replaced by `addContainerProvider`. With version 2.3.x this method was removed.

That was the [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3864) with the struts2-archetype-blank.I believe you need to change the following settings

```
configurationManager.addConfigurationProvider(c);
```

to this:

```
configurationManager.addContainerProvider( c );
```

I hope this fill fix your issue

Comment: Thanks! @Umesh Awasthi
I was really hesitant to change it to addContainerProvider thanks for clarifying the reason behind (bug) 
Hope they fix that soon

Comment: @royjavelosa:it's fixed now,might come in next release.